# Trying to open Spyder from Anaconda but getting the error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets'

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, modulenotfounderror

I am trying to launch Spyder from within the anaconda navigator but I am persistently getting the error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets'. When I tried to resolve this by opening a terminal window and running

```
pip install pyqt5
```

it returned error:

```
metadata-generation-failed
```

I've tried to wipe anaconda entirely from my machine and reinstall it, but this error keeps occurring. I've got no idea what to do.

Comment: Use `conda install -c anaconda pyqt ` and `conda install -c conda-forge pyqtwebengine`

Comment: Hi! I did this and the conda install -c conda-forge pyqtwebengine returned many "conflicts" and now when I try to open Spyder, I get /Users/dharmikpatel/opt/anaconda3/bin/pythonw: line 3: /Users/dharmikpatel/opt/anaconda3/python.app/Contents/MacOS/python: No such file or directory. Is there something I can do to resolve this?